# How to forward fill the year and the corresponding values in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with 2 columns of period and inventory code as below. I want to forward fill the year for each inventory item from their starting year all the way to 2022. The yellow highlighted are the rows I want to fill for each inventory item. What would be the way to do this? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
list_year =[2018, 2018, 2019,  2020, 2020, 2021, 2021,  2022]
list_inv = ['TTO', 'TZA', 'OMN', 'RUS', 'SUR',   'TUR', 'USA', 'VAT']

df_test = pd.DataFrame({'period':list_year, 'inventory code': list_inv})
```

I have a dataframe like this - I have year as period and inventory code for each year. In my real dataset, I have different number of rows (inventory code) associated with each year.

[image]

I want to forward fill the years for all inventory code.

For example, there are two inventory items in the year of 2018, I want to insert 2 rows for each of these 2 inventory item for each of the future year till 2022.

Be noted I don't need to backfill the information for previous year. For example, there are two inventory items in 2019, and I don't need to insert two rows for them for the year of 2018.

Below highlighted are the rows I want to fill for each inventory item

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forward filling via `ffill` makes only sense, when you have `NaN` values, that are to be replaced by the last valid one. Hence, you would need to add rows with `NaN` for each inventory code and an incremented period.

Alternatively, you could append a dataframe with the missing rows directly:

```
#identify maximum period
maxPeriod = df_test.period.max()

#initialize resulting dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['period', 'inventory code'])

#step through each period and append the group of inventory codes for each period until maxPeriod
for currentPeriod, group in df_test.groupby(['period']):
    for newPeriod in range(currentPeriod, maxPeriod+1):
        df = df.append( group.replace(currentPeriod, newPeriod), ignore_index=True )

#output of df:
#   period inventory code
#0    2018            TTO
#1    2018            TZA
#2    2019            TTO
#3    2019            TZA
#4    2020            TTO
#5    2020            TZA
#6    2021            TTO
#7    2021            TZA
#8    2022            TTO
#9    2022            TZA
#10   2019            OMN
#11   2020            OMN
#12   2021            OMN
#13   2022            OMN
#14   2020            RUS
#15   2020            SUR
#16   2021            RUS
#17   2021            SUR
#18   2022            RUS
#19   2022            SUR
#20   2021            TUR
#21   2021            USA
#22   2022            TUR
#23   2022            USA
#24   2022            VAT
```

Answer (score 1):

Below would be my answer

```
# Restructure the data
df_table = df_test.groupby(['period','inventory code'])['inventory 
code'].max().unstack([1])

# forward fill the value
for col in df_table.columns:
    df_table[col] = df_table[col].fillna(method='ffill').fillna('')

df_table['period'] = df_table.index.get_level_values(0)
df_final = pd.melt(df_table, id_vars = 'period')

df_final.drop(columns='inventory code',inplace=True)

df_final = df_final[df_final['value']!='']
df_final.sort_values(by='period').head()
```

[image]